# How to get admin session(user) details on front side in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, backend, session

In order to restrict front side access for some admin user i need currently logged in admin user details at front side.

I have tried to get the admin session details as per below but not getting details.

**Variable:** `protected $_adminSession;`

**Model:** `Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session $adminSession`

**Function:**

```
$this->_adminSession->hasUser() ? (int)$this->_adminSession->getUser()->getId() : null;
```

Above call gives me blank value.

If someone have idea regarding the same please share here.

Answer (score 5):

This is not possible.
Frontend and backend are separate applications and use separate sessions.
It's the same thing as Magento 1.

Answer (score 0):

This should return admin user id.

```
$adminSession->getUser()->getData('user_id')
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for answering. I will get back to you after I tried.

Comment: its not working for me...