# Redirect user to either admin or frontend based on login status

Tags: magento2, admin, session

I want to build a custom controller, which works as follows:

1. if user already have admin session, redirect user to admin page A
2. if user does not have admin session, redirect user to storefront page B

Is there a way to achieve this?

First I tried building custom logic in `adminhtml/controller` but it didn't work because for case (2), magento shows admin login UI even before any of my controller logic runs.
Then I tried building custom logic in frontend controller but that won't work for case (1) because it's not possible from frontend to tell admin session ( [How to get admin session(user) details on front side in Magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/101473/how-to-get-admin-sessionuser-details-on-front-side-in-magento-2/108527#108527) )

Any advise would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use event controller_action_predispatch as it calls before any controller action dispatch

Comment: no luck, it seems like controller_action_predispatch runs for `adminhtml_auth_login` but not for my controller